# How does a battery work and create a field inside it?

Tags: potential, voltage, physical-chemistry, batteries

There is an explanation of how a battery works that says that inside the battery (in the positive charge convention) there is a field and the battery does work on the positive charge against the field to move it from the negative terminal to the positive terminal and it becomes full of potential energy, ready to be used in a circuit.

But from what I understand from a battery (an excess of electrons on one side and a lack of electrons on the other side) there isn't a field inside the battery and the battery doesn't take a charge and move it from one side to the other so it gains potential energy.

What I need is a chemical detailed explanation of how a battery works that tells more about how the battery's electric field is created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why electrons flow through a wire connected to a battery?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247725/)

Comment: There should exist some reason(s)  not to believe/accept some theory; do add that here; also, energy comes __outside__ from the field around the circuit (must have heard of Poynting vector; check its orientation for a circuit) and not along the wire, as you might deduce from the theory above.

Comment: See also: [What is the difference between a battery and a charged capacitor?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32391/)

Comment: have a look here  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/battery.html and here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/leadacid.html

Answer (score 2):

Batteries work by chemical reactions. The current inside a battery is an ion current. And the main point to realize is that the ion current is driven be a concentration gradient, and that it is in a direction opposite to the electric field inside the battery.